# Is there a way to use VBA to click on a button on a website?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to click on a button labeled "CSV" on this website but it is giving me trouble. I can get VBA to open the website but not actually click the button. Any suggestions on the code would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub website_test() 

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim ht As HTMLDocument
    Dim button As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 5
    
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        
        ie.navigate ("https://www.dailyfantasyfuel.com/nfl/projections/fanduel/2022-09-11/")
        
        Do Until ie.readyState = 4
           DoEvents
        Loop
            
        Set ht = ie.document
        
        Set elems = ht.getElementsByClassName("title may-blank")
        
        For Each elem In elems
            Debug.Print (elem.innerText)
        Next
        Set button = ht.querySelector("span class=hov-underline")
        button.Click
        ie.Quit
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you run your code? "trouble" is a little non-specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TimWilliams As per the problem statement it won't click the desired button that I want it to.

Comment: So - it just loads the page and then nothing happens after that, and you don't get any error messages?

Comment: @TimWilliams I get an error on the line:                                                                                                        Set button = ht.querySelector("span class=hov-underline")                                                       I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting an error here maybe not importing HTML properly. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: When posting here it's useful to describe exactly what happens when your code isn't working as you want - that includes the specific error message text and anything else folks here could use to help you get it fixed.  Try `Set button = ht.querySelector("span.hov-underline")`

Comment: @TimWilliams That worked thank you! I guess my followup question would be do I have to use internet explorer or can vba use Microsoft Edge?

Comment: You can use Selenium Basic if you want to use a different browser.  Eg see https://www.guru99.com/excel-vba-selenium.html

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok only reason I ask is that once the button is clicked on the URL it brings up Microsoft Explorer downloads which I'm not sure I would Save a document from there.

Comment: Take a look at some of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=IE+vba+click+save+on+download+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @TimWilliams You my friend are an absolute animal. Thank you so much for your help tonight. I have exactly what I needed

Comment: Good to hear you're on-track.